# Can you hook an existing Elasticsearch index to Elastic App search

Tags: elasticsearch, app-search

I want to integrate App Search in my project. App search runs fine out of the box. But I have an application that is running on Elasticsearch, I was wondering if I could use this existing index as a backend for App search? If No, is it because documents are indexed differently for App Search engine compared to Elasticsearch? Also, why can't I access App search documents on my elasticsearch cluster (localhost:9200)?

Comment: You should describe your problem in detail.

Comment: @Johnny, the question is pretty clear. Sanshila, it seems like we're forced to re-inject in AppSearch.